# Fatal error: Class 'Drush\Log\Logger' not found

Tags: drush

Hi I'm getting this Drush error no matter which command I try.

> Fatal error: Class 'Drush\Log\Logger' not found

How can I fix it?

I haven't been able to find other users reporting the same issue. I'm using Drush 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same problem after updating core with drush (installed with composer). This is not something you should do if drupal is installed in the root directory, I've now learned. Reinstalling drush fixed the issue for me.

```
composer require drush/drush
```

Next step, I guess if we want to avoid this in the future, is to either move drupal to a subdirectory (as a dependency) or uninstall drush as a composer package and install it globally instead (the old fashioned way).

Comment: weird, but worked for me. Thanks. Worth noting that if you have your alias file in the site's drush folder it'll get overwritten by reinstalling drush

Answer (score 0):

This is causing due to latest drush 10.2.2 and Drupal 8.8.5, I installed drush9 on my project
composer require drush/drush:^9
And it fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently on Acquia Cloud running Drush 10.4.0 and Drupal 8.9.13. The solution was to SSH into the application and run `drush cr`.

You need to follow the instructions here to ensure the `--root` option is specified correctly: https://docs.acquia.com/cloud-platform/manage/ssh/drush/